# How to get this.setState to work in React-Native

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am struggling to get this.setState to work with react-native. I keep getting this.setState is not a function error. I am using an arrow function, which i thought would use the enclosing scope and  there was no need to bind to this. But it is not working as expected. I appreciate any help i can get.

```
   **
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */

import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  state = {
    textValue: 'Original Text'
  };

  buttonPress = () => this.setState({textValue: 'New Text'})



  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView
          contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
          style={styles.scrollView}>
          <Header />
          {global.HermesInternal == null ? null : (
            <View style={styles.engine}>
              <Text style={styles.footer}>Engine: Hermes</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          <View style={styles.body}>
          <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>{this.state.textValue}</Text>
              <Button
                onPress={buttonPress}
                title="Learn More"
                color="#841584"
                accessibilityLabel="This is a button"
              />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Step One</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                Edit <Text style={styles.highlight}>App.js</Text> to change this
                screen and then come back to see your edits.
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>See Your Changes</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                <ReloadInstructions />
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Debug</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                <DebugInstructions />
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Learn More</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                Read the docs to discover what to do next:
              </Text>
            </View>
            <LearnMoreLinks />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
  },
  engine: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
  },
  body: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  },
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: Colors.black,
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: Colors.dark,
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
  footer: {
    color: Colors.dark,
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: '600',
    padding: 4,
    paddingRight: 12,
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState('Original Text')

  buttonPress = () => setTextValue('New Text')
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the setState feature, class definition is required. Like this.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructer(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
     textValue: 'Original Text'
    };
  }

  buttonPress = () => this.setState({textValue: 'New Text'})

  render () {
    return (
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

If you want to use the function, please read the document.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html